# Windows 2003 server with oracle freezes

Tags: windows-server-2003, oracle

I am newbie to servers n all.. Please do help.

We are having a windows 2003 machine with the latest hardware configuration (i3 processor) which runs an ORACLE 8 Database server. The machine freezes after some time. there is no particular event happening. after 2-3 restarts the machine may work perfectly.

Some events from the event viewer are the following:

> - APPLICATION ERROR: Faulting application STRTDB80.EXE, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x00000000.
> - SYSTEM ERROR: SOURCE:MRxSmb DESC:The master browser has received a server announcement from the computer ELE-CEEL-C124 that believes that it is the master browser for the domain on transport NetBT_Tcpip_{E648850B-E70B-. The master browser is stopping or an election is being forced.
> - SOURCE:Service Control Manager DESC:The OracleStartORCL service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).
> - SOURCE:Service Control Manager DESC:The Windows Boot service terminated with the following error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
> - SOURCE:Service Control Manager DESC:The Config Installer service terminated with the following error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Can anyone suggest a solution? :(

Comment: You're going to have to give us more to go on than that. Error logs, perfmon counters, etc.

Comment: can u tell me wht all should i chk, i will give them.

Comment: Faulting application STRTDB80.EXE, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x00000000.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

THis error is occuring on startup..

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional info.

Comment: please check the question now.

Comment: "can u tell me wht all should i chk, i will give them" Please use real words.

Comment: ok John. i will consider this.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle 8 is not supported on Windows 2003, the earliest version supported is Oracle 9i.